# Use a callback and dynamically adapt if it's instance function or simple function

Tags: python

The following code:

```
def foo(a):
    print(a)

class Bar(object):
    def foo(self, a):
        print(a)
bar = Bar()


class A(object):
    callback1 = foo
    callback2 = bar.foo

    def do(self):
        self.callback2(1)
        self.callback1(1)


A().do()
```

Produce following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bastien/Projects/test/t.py", line 19, in <module>
    A().do()
  File "/home/bastien/Projects/test/t.py", line 16, in do
    self.callback1(1)
TypeError: foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Because `foo` function is used like an instance function. I can add a `@staticmethod` decorator on `foo` function but is it possible to adapt `A.do` to use callback as simple function when it is (consider we cannot know before `A.do` execution) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of callback can be used to correctly prepare the callback:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import types


def foo(a):
    print(a)

class Bar(object):
    def foo(self, a):
        print(a)
bar = Bar()


def prepare_callback(callback):
    if isinstance(callback, types.FunctionType):
        return lambda self, *args, **kwargs: callback(*args, **kwargs)
    return callback


class A(object):
    callback1 = prepare_callback(foo)
    callback2 = prepare_callback(bar.foo)

    def do(self):
        self.callback2(1)
        self.callback1(1)


A().do()
```

But, smarter way is to not use class attributes:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def foo(a):
    print(a)

class Bar(object):
    def foo(self, a):
        print(a)
bar = Bar()


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, callback1, callback2):
        self.callback1 = callback1
        self.callback2 = callback2

    def do(self):
        self.callback1(1)
        self.callback2(1)


A(foo, bar.foo).do()
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling the first `foo` function via a dot reference transforms it into an instance method which would normally pass the instance as first argument asides the existing arguments; making the number of passed arguments two, mismatching foo's signature.

To boycott the effect of this function-method transformation, you can call the original function object using `__func__`:

```
class A(object):
    callback1 = foo
    callback2 = bar.foo

    def do(self):
        self.callback2(1)
        self.callback1.__func__(1)
```

Keep in mind that `foo` is a *vanilla* function, while `bar.foo` is a bound method.

Comment: You miss this part of question: "consider we cannot know before A.do execution"

Comment: @bux Are you on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I use Python 3.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following code:

```
callback = foo.__func__ if "__func__" in foo.__dir__() else foo
```